# WatchOS 4: "Byte count limit reached" when accessing UserDefaults

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch

I got the following error on the apple watch

```
2018-01-21 19:12:46.144394+0100 nightguard[242:13146] [User Defaults] CFPrefsPlistSource<0x155ad5c0> enter code here`(Domain: group.de.my-wan.dhe.nightguard, User: kCFPreferencesCurrentUser, ByHost: No, Container: (null), Contents Need Refresh: Yes): Byte count limit reached
```

This error seems to happen right after executing the following code:

```
guard let defaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: AppConstants.APP_GROUP_ID) else {
            ... // shouldn't matter
}
let value = defaults.float(forKey: "maximumBloodGlucoseDisplayed")
```

The app closes afterwards. When looking at the code comments in UserDefaults class, apple says that there should be a limit for tvOS only:

> NSUserDefaultsSizeLimitExceededNotification is posted on the main queue when more data is stored in user defaults than is allowed. Currently there is no limit for local user defaults except on tvOS, where a warning notification will be posted at 512kB, and the process terminated at 1MB. For ubiquitous defaults, the limit depends on the logged in iCloud user.

We noticed this problem after updating to IOS 11. So maybe the limit has been introduced by IOS 11.

Maybe someone can shed some light on this or can tell me what the reason for this error really is.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, due to a bug, I was writing some Megabytes of data into the UserDefaults. This wasn't a problem before WatchOS 4, but it really seems that apple has limited this in WatchOS 4.

The same data amount is no problem using iOS 11. The error message occurs on WatchOS only.

So it seems that apple should update their API documentation ;-)